# Android Emulator not getting started..nor m able to start new avd and old avd not geting repaired also

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image: after clicking on ok button nothing happens .not able to repair i updated my sdk a day ago is that y its not working out pls hurry on the solution guys]

after clicking on ok button nothing happens .not able to repair i updated my sdk a day ago is that y its not working out pls hurry on the solution guys..
Error on the previously created device is that the the configuration has changed !!

Answer (score 0):

Give 100MiB to SD card & use GPU acceleration.
See if that helps.

### Edit:

Try to create and run an AVD from the command-line. Learn how to do it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html).

Comment: :: Still no ..is new installation lead to this problem